# MySQL: Multiple values search within aggregated string

Tags: mysql, sphinxql

If I have such as table below

```
|---col_1---|---col_2-----|
|---19------| "A; E; C; H"|
|---23------| "B; E; C"   |
|---24------| "O; D"      |
```

where `col_2` is GROUP_CONCATed (by semicolon) column and I'm passing `"E; A; C"`, I want to SELECT `19, 23` because at least 1 word (separated with semicolon) matches.

Can not figure out how to do it as MySQL query?

P.S.: This will be used in SphinxQL (Sphinx search engine Query Lang), which is similar to MySQL.

Comment: Simple. Don't have a "GROUP_CONCATenated column" (whatever that is).

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close this question as "too broad". Doing waht you ask -- searching a denormalized column (GROUP_CONCATed) with a denormalized search term -- is **very hard** to do in pure MySQL query language. It will take dozens of poorly performing lines of query language. If you can normalize your data, spend your effort doing that. If you can't, look at `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index.  Or, maybe, look at the ads in the right column of this fine web site. :-)

Comment: thanks, guys, I've already been given answer I want. please take a look at this forum's answer. I'm closing this. http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=15476